# How to fix an IllegalThreadStateException in Spring Batch in the ItemWriter using a JPA repository

Tags: multithreading, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch app that is reading couple of million records from an Azure SQL db (P11), does some calls, then updates those records. Below is the configuration of that particular step.
The 'chunksize' is 400 and the 'throttleLimit' is 30

```
    @Bean
    public Step coreCardProcessStep(JpaPagingItemReader<CoreCardEntity> sqlCoreLoadItemReader,
                                    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                                    OutCoreCardProcessor outCoreCardProcessor,
                                    CoreProcessStepCardWriter coreProcessStepCardWriter
    ) {
        log.info("coreCardProcessingStep: creating a step for processing sql rows");
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("CORE_CARD_PROCESSOR STEP 001")
                .<CoreCardEntity, CoreCardEntity>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(sqlCoreLoadItemReader)
                .processor(outCoreCardProcessor)
                .writer(coreProcessStepCardWriter)
                .taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("coreCardLoad"))
                .throttleLimit(throttleLimit)
                .build();
    }
```

My writer is actually a JPA writer but implemented ourselves

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CoreProcessStepCardWriter implements ItemWriter<CoreCardEntity> {

    private final CoreCardRepository coreCardRepository;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends CoreCardEntity> coreCards) throws Exception {
        log.info("write: number of cards: {}", coreCards.size());

        coreCardRepository.saveAll(coreCards);
    }
}
```

The problem is that after already processed a few 10000 records correctly I somehow get an IllegalThreadStateException which as far as I know can only happen if something tries to start a Thread that is already started. The exception is thrown from the writer just when it tries to saveAll and it happens on all concurrent chunks. This is the stacktrace of the actual underlying problem (Spring Batch itself is wrapping all exceptions from each chunk up in something else after the failure):

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy225.saveAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.abnamro.pim.loader.cardmigration.services.batches.out.core.steps.writers.CoreProcessStepCardWriter.write(CoreProcessStepCardWriter.java:25)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:193)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:294)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:217)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3759)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:268)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:242)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:456)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor198.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:118)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy208.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2440)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4521)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4511)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:571)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:539)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2100(SessionImpl.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2835)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2812)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2768)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2812)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1024)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:816)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor306.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy222.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:669)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:700)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor316.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 20 more
```

I don't quite understand how this happens, let alone how to fix it. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a multi-threaded step, the batch artifacts (reader, writer, etc) should be thread-safe. Please refer to the documentation here: [Multi-threaded Step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep). In your case, you should synchronize your item writer or make it step-scoped.

Another option is to use a partitioned step (instead of a multi-threaded step), where each partition is a distinct data set that is processed by a distinct worker thread.

---

As a side note, I'd recommend using a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, because the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` does not re-use threads.

Comment: Tried with the thread safe JPAItemWriter and scoped it to the step. Ultimately made no difference. This exception still happens as soon as the entitymanager tries to flush, from the looks of it the DB transaction itself does not seem to be threadsafe or something.